# How to hide git bash terminal during execution like when downloading?

Tags: console, git-bash

I want to hide Git bash console (close not minimized) during execution like when a file is downloading in background via bash in localhost xampp.

Answer (score 1):

You can `nohup` the git process. `nohup` keeps git running even when you close the terminal.

```
nohup git fetch & exit
```

Note that you won't be able to make any input, so stay away from commands like `git pull` that may expect input. You could use GNU screen to run these commands.

**Alternative:**
Sounds like you don't want to use the console at all. Maybe you should try a graphical software for your file manager, like RabbitVCS for Nautilus, Nemo, and Thunar on Linux, or TortoiseGit for Explorer on Windows.

Comment: nemo-rabbitvcs is not available as a nemo extension (at least in Linux Mint 19.1)

Comment: @juagicre Did you mean not available **using the package manager**? I did not test it, but there is an [official extension for nemo](https://github.com/rabbitvcs/rabbitvcs/tree/master/clients/nemo). That extension can be installed by hand, see README under the link above.

Comment: Not in the package manager, as you say. Even there is a nemo extension from rabbitvcs (also as you say) it looks to be out-dated... There are some issues in the github pointing that it does not work even installing it manually.

Comment: Yeah, there are few discussions suggesting that the plugin is outdated, but [some people](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=273172) had luck with installing the packages from Mint 18.3.